# PC keeps waking up from hybrid standby

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate, wake-up

If I put my PC into hybrid standby, every ~ 15 minutes it wakes itself up, mostly just showing a black screen and going to standby a few seconds later, all by itslef.

I already looked into the allowed waking devices via `powercfg`, which shows mouse, keyboard and network card, and even after physically disconnecting mouse, keyboard and ethernet cable, the PC keeps on waking up.

Also, it is not the case that this is the automatic Windows update task; I disabled that after it kept waking up at exactly 3:00 at night.

I was not able to find any automated Windows tasks via the cr*ppy Windows board-tools which are allowed to wake the PC. But if you know any other tools to capable to find those, feel free to tell me.

Also please note, that this issue occurs on standby and hybrid standby, but appearently not on hibernate mode.

---

Board: Z97 GAMING 7
I don't know the BIOS version right now

---

Update: I did disable the waking option completely, as proposed, and it STILL wakes up every 15 minutes. How is this even possible. This is what `powercfg -lastwake` says:

> Aktivierungsverlaufsanzahl - 1
>   Aktivierungsverlauf [0]
>     Aktivierungsquellenanzahl  - 0

(Sorry it is only in german, I think you will know what it says - nothing helpful, actually)

Also see some event logs, please tell me if you prefer the .evtx file or some other information: http://pastebin.com/c1kcgS4q

Comment: You might like to add the make of PC, motherboard , BIOS version etc to the question

Answer (score 0):

Check out the different between hybrid standby and hibernation:

[Sleep and hibernation: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions)

There is some program that you are running is trying to wake up the PC, since hybrid standby is not fully power down the PC, the PC can be waked up. However, hibernate is totally power down the PC, no power source is required, so it can't be waked up.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the difference. But the question is, what is the program that is keeping to wake the PC up? How can I find out, and disable it? I would definitely prefer standby as the waking process is much faster.

Comment: Please run command prompt as admin and execute `powercfg -lastwake`, post the result

Comment: Will try again when I'm at home. But as I recall, there never was anyhing or anything helpful at least

Comment: Another lazy way: if you dont want any application to wake up your PC, you can adjust the power plan to disable the wake timer, screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bTwa5.png

Comment: Definitely a good workaround, will give that a try later on. Though I would prefer a cleaner way, so I can set the PC to wake-on-lan some time.

Comment: How can it be that it still wakes up, when I disabled the wake timer?